How do I prevent 429 Too Many Requests in Angular?
I tried using delay(50) on each API call, but I still get 429 Too Many Requests. Back-end is Laravel, what's the best way to prevent this in Angular or should this be handled by back-end Laravel?
My code look like this
export class PdoProgramComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadPdoPrograms();
  }
  // Load all PDO programs from DB
  loadPdoPrograms() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.pdoService.getAssigendPdos().pipe(
      take(1),
      map(res => this.sortPdosByName(res.results.pdos)),
      switchMap(pdos => this.validatePdoPrograms(pdos)),
      catchError(err => {
        this.showAlertSavingFailed();
        return of([]);
      })
    ).subscribe({
      next: (pdos: Pdo[]) => this.pdos = pdos,
      complete: () => this.isLoading = false
    });
  }
  validatePdoPrograms(pdos: Pdo[]): Observable<Pdo[]> {
    return from(pdos).pipe(
      concatMap(pdo => of(pdo).pipe(
        delay(50), // Delay each call by 50 milliseconds
        switchMap(() => this.pdoService.getSpecificPdoAdvocaiesPrograms(pdo.id).pipe(
          take(1),
          map(res => {
            const pdo_advocacies = res.results.pdo?.pdo_advocacies;
            pdo.editRequiredCount = 0;

            pdo_advocacies.forEach(advocacy => {
              if (advocacy.advocacy !== 'Unrestricted') {
                pdo.editRequiredCount += advocacy.pdo_programs.filter(
                  program => program.admin_advocacies.length === 0 ||
                    !program.admin_beneficiary_category ||
                    !program.program_category
                ).length;
              }
            });

            return pdo;
          })
        ))
      )),
      toArray()
    );
  }

}


You could adjust your rate limiting config in laravel, but it would just temporary fix the issue. The real solution would be reduce the number of request required for your program to work. It looks like you are doing one request per "PDO Advocacy" to validate it. Could you send a list of "PDO Advocacies" and validated them all at one ? One query versus N queries.

@lance2k create a Api that does all the validation on the server and just returns the result. Unless you are constrained to change the API, this is the best solution

thanks for the confirmation, I thought of the same solution.
